# How to control the number of lines that surround each difference when running `git diff`?

Tags: git, version-control

Depending on what I am `diff`ing  sometimes I want to see several lines (let's say 10) above and below the `+`insertions `-`deletions, sometimes I just want to see a couple of lines surrounding them.

Is there a way to tell git the number of line he should show me?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The option you're looking for is `-U`. From the man page:

> `-U<n>, --unified=<n>`
>
> Generate diffs with  lines of context instead of the usual three. Implies -p.

Comment: This is it!. I never thought that `U` or `unified` could mean number of lines of context though

Comment: @nacho4d: The Git man pages may not always be the best for high-level tutorials, but in terms of options for commands, they're pretty complete: searching `man git-diff` for "context" gets you there pretty fast. (And yeah, it's a bit unusual - probably because `-C` was already taken.)

Comment: \o/ it works for `show` too, and presumably any/most other options that ultimately delegate to `diff`

Comment: Just pointing out it's an upper case 'U'

Answer (score 13):

`git diff -U<num>`. Default is 3.

Comment: This answer doesn't provide any information not included in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8075023/38765

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, Looks like Robert posted his solution "almost" at the same time. As for me it can be treated as "independent" answer as well.